# SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_gangs/server.lue:99:attempt to index a nil value (field '?')

Tags: syntax-error

1.';local gangData = {
2.    name = _gang,
3.  gang_grade = tonumber(_grade),
4.  gang_name = ESX.Gangs[gang].ranks[tonumber(grade)].label,
5.  gang_grade_label = ESX.Gangs[gang].ranks[tonumber(grade)].label,
6.  gang_grade_name = ESX.Gangs[gang].ranks[tonumber(grade)].name
7.  }
8.  TriggerClientEvent ('esx_gangs:UpdateGang', player, gangData)
end)

Comment: What even is that ? Can you give us a bit of context ?

Comment: u do not know im new

Comment: Don't see how this is relevant tbh. Somebody new can totally ask a well formatted question and explain his issue properly as far as I know. And, I do actually know that you're new since you're in the "first posts" review queue. This is how I stumbled upon your question.